# Why doesn't pear recognize regex in phpt tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpt

I'm trying to write a test for a PHPUnit extiontion I'm working on which needs a regex matcher in the expected section of the test.

The documentations of PHPT file states that there is a `%r` flag which can be used to match regex in the `--EXPECTF--` section of the test. You can get more details from: [PHPT - Test File Layout](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php)

I tried to use it in my tests, but it always fail! So I decided to write a simple test to check the problem and the test looked like this:

```
--TEST--
Test the %r tag of EXPECTF in phpt
--FILE--
<?php

echo '1';

?>
--EXPECTF--
%r.%r
```

This test fails when I run it using pear's `run-tests` command. The `.diff` file contains the following:

```
001- %r.%r
001+ 1
```

It seems as if this tag doesn't get recognized by the tests runner. So I tried to find an example which uses this tag in the tests of the source of PHP. There was only one test to be found using it (inside: php-src-5.3/ext/standard/tests/network/gethostbyaddr_basic1.phpt).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works with the `run-tests.php` that comes with the PHP source distribution (in its root), not with PEAR's version.

```
PHPRC=. TEST_PHP_EXECUTABLE=./sapi/cli/php php run-tests.php a.phpt
```

```
PASS Test the %r tag of EXPECTF in phpt [a.phpt]
```

If you take a look at PEAR's version in `<PHP prefix>/lib/php/PEAR/RunTest.php` around line 520, you'll notice it doesn't support `%r`.

Comment: `--EXPECTREGEX--` will parse the whole section below it as regex. I'm trying to parse a PART of the output with regex.